# New to Python, could use some guidance on a basic problem

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a basic problem where I'm given the float 3.142, the question asks to make a list that uses numbers 1 2 3 but only using 3.142 to get those numbers in the list. I know that int(3.142) gives 3; int(3.142/3.142) gives 1, but I'm not sure how to get 2. Is there some sort of mathematical function that I'm not considering?

Thank you

Comment: `list(range(1, int(3.142) + 1))`

Comment: He can't use 1 :(.

Comment: Hint: 1 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 5):

Well, to get 2 you can do `(3.142 + 3.142) / 3.142` :).

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to convert back and forth between strings:

```
# convert float to a string
num = 3.142
strnum = str(num)

# order the string lexicographically, using built-in method sorted
ordered = sorted(strnum)
# ordered = ['.', '1', '2', '3', '4']

# get the middle three elements at indices 1, 2, and 3, using a list slice
middle = ordered[1:4]
# middle = ['1', '2', '3']

# convert them into integers if desired, using a list comprehension
middle_ints = [int(e) for e in middle]
# middle_ints = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

We, programmers like code that follow DRY principle (do not repeat yourself)

To get more DRY code for both 1 and 2, without repeating your constant use square.

```
import math

int(math.sqrt(3.142) == 1

round(math.sqrt(3.142)) == 2
```

:)

Answer (score -1):

You may use the operator '%' and get 2.

```
int(3.142) = 3
int(3.142 % 3.142) = 2
int(3.142 / 3.142) = 1
```

Comment: Where are you getting `int(3.142 % 3.142) == 2` from? It checks out as 0 in my interpreter, like it should.

Comment: Are you sure of the second one? Last time I checked `x % x = 0`